# Rollback Datastore PUT Transaction in GAE Python Web

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, rollback

There is one method inside that method I'm inserting three different models record into database. But if some exception or error happens I need to rollback this insertion transaction from db.
Following is show case of method.

```
def post():
    try:
        model1 = Model1()
        model1.key1 = 'key1'
        model1.key2 = 'key2'
        model1.put()

        #some logic1 code block goes here
        .
        .
        model2 = Model2()
        model2.key2 = 'key2'
        model2.key2 = 'key2'
        model2.put()

        #some logic2 code block goes here
        .
        .
        model3 = Model3()
        model3.key3 = 'key3'
        model3.key3 = 'key3'
        model3.put()

        #some logic3 block goes here
        .
        .
    except Exception:
        #all the database insertion transaction which happened should be rollback here.
```

**Here Model1, Model2 and Model3 are google.appengine.ext.ndb.Model extending model classes.**
Now suppose exception occurred in `logic1 code block` then `model1` should be rollback because it was inserted before executing this `logic1 code block`. Similarly if exception occurred in `logic2 code block` then both above `model1 & model2` should be rollback and so on. My problem is very common. I did lot of search but not able to find any solution. I'm totaly new in Python and GAE. Please help.

Comment: I don't believe you did "a lot of search" but couldn't find the solution. A simple search for "NDB Transaction" returns [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions).

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But i think it is not helping me. i want to do rollback of my inserted records if some error occurred after record insertion into database. When i used @ndb.transactional, it was not working. It will be more helpful if you give some solution/idea for answer instead of documentation link.

Comment: You put the decorator around all the logic that could cause the exception.

Comment: Sorry, but still didn't get any solution from your comment. My question is very simple. I need to do rollback(for all the inserted records) if exception occurred at any line of code in above post() method.

Answer (score -1):

As [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) linked for you, the answer is on the [NDB Transaction page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions). Just search for the word "rollback" and you'll see it.

For your code, this means:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def post():
    try:
        model1 = Model1()
        model1.key1 = 'key1'
        model1.key2 = 'key2'
        model1.put()

        ...

        #some logic3 block goes here
        .
        .
    except Exception:
        #all the database insertion transaction which happened should be rollback here.
        raise ndb.Rollback
```

Note that on the decorator I've specified `xg-True` since from your code snippet it looked like it was most likely a cross-entity group transaction. If this is not the case and all entities have the same root ancestor, you can omit this.

Also note that ndb.Rollback is purely a convenience exception - any exception raised in a transaction decorated function will cause a rollback.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, but when i implemented this in my current code, i'm getting "BadRequestError: Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions" exception. I'm completely new in Python and GAE. This exception thrown while i'm fetching record from database using ndb.query() method.

Comment: @vijayshegokar - your question only shows puts and gets - Datastore queries are an important detail you shouldn't leave out. As per documentation you can only query by ancestors inside of transactions. You shouldn't have any other type of query here anyway, since it's only eventually consistent without an ancestor restriction. You will need to rethink your design. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions